# Conceptual question on Schur Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

According to my textbook, Schur Theorem is stated as follows:

Let T be a linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space V. Suppose that the characteristic polynomial of T splits. Then there exists an orthonormal basis $\beta$ for V such that the matrix $[T]_\beta$ is upper triangular.

Then it goes on to say that if such an orthonormal basis $\beta$ exists, then $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

My question is if that is the case why not the theorem just says that the matrix $[T]_\beta$ is diagonal? Why does it say upper triangular instead? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: From a logical point of view, as you phrased it, it might be the case, that there exists an orthonormal basis with upper triangular matrices, even though the characteristic polynomial doesn't split. Then, according to the second implication, also in this case the matrices would be diagonal. If that is mathematically possible, I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing Schur's theorem with diagonalization. Schur's theorem says if there are $n$ eigenvalues (a result of c.h.p. being split), then it is possible to find an orthonormal basis $\beta$ for $V$ s.t. $[T]_\beta$ is upper triangular. See for example [here](http://course.ee.ust.hk/elec560/Lectures/ch3.pdf)-Thm 3.7 for a neat proof. If $[T]_\beta$ is diagonal, then $\beta$ are necessarily eigenvectors of $T$ (check it yourself). Schur's theorem never says $\beta$ is the eigenvectors of $T$ (but it could be). So $[T]_\beta$ is not necessarily diagonal.

Certain additional conditions can ensure $\beta$ to be the eigenvectors of $T$, in which case $[T]]_\beta$ is diagonal. For example, if:

- $T$ is a symmetric (hermitian) matrix
- $T$ is a skew-symmetric (skew-hermitian) matrix
- $T$ is a normal matrix.

  (You may want to check Peter Lax's Linear Algebra)

It is possible that $T$ is diagonal in the general case, for example all eigenvalues are distinct (leaving no possibility to have Jordan blocks). However, the diagonalization should be done by a similarity transformation $M^{-1}TM$ instead of a congruence transformation $M^*TM$ in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Now I have figured it out

what I was misunderstanding.

we cannot say that z is an eigenvector of T since we don't have the condition that

T is normal. (when T is normal T star's eigenvector is also an eigenvector of T)

so T(z) must be expressed as linear combination of all the elements of basis

so we can only claim that matrix representation of T with respect to {z} U Gamma

is upper triangular